# Rpsec and Factory Girl not cooperating

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm kind of pulling my hair out on this one.  I'm trying to test using rspec and Factory Girl (Ubuntu 13.10 and Rails 4).  It seems as if Rspec doesn't see any of the Factory Girl stuff.  Here's my spec_helper.rb:

```
    # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
     require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
     require 'factory_girl_rails'
     require 'rspec/rails'
     require 'rspec/autorun'
     require 'capybara/rspec'

     Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

     ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

     RSpec.configure do |config|
       config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

       config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

       config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

       config.order = "random"
         config.color_enabled = true

         config.tty = true

         config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate
     end
```

factories.rb:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :exercise do
        name 'New Exercise'
        time 3
        reps 7
        weight 12
        weight_unit 'kg'
        factory :aerobic_exercise do
         name 'Jumping Jacks'
          kind 'Cardio/Aerobic'
        end
        factory :bodyweight_exercise do
          name 'Pushups'
          kind 'Bodyweight'
        end
        factory :cardio_exercise do
          name 'Jumping Jacks'
          kind 'Cardio/Aerobic'
        end
        factory :lifting_exercise do
          name 'BB Shoulder Presses'
          kind 'Weight Lifting'
        end
      end
    end
```

and my failing spec:

```
    #require 'test/spec'
    require 'spec_helper'

    describe Exercise do
      describe 'Exercise properly normalizes values' do
        it 'has weight and weight unit if kind is Weight Lifting' do
          let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:lifting_exercise) }
         exercise.should be_weight
          exercise.time.should be_nil
        end
        it 'has time but not weight etc. if kind is Cardio' do
          let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:aerobic_exercise) }
          exercise.should be_time
          exercise.reps.should be_nil
        end
      end
    end
```

When I run rspec I get this error:

```
         Failure/Error: let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:lifting_exercise) }
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `let' for #    <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007f2f013b3760>
```

HELP!(please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `let` method isn't from FactoryGirl, it's from Rspec, and the issue is that `let` should not be nested within the `it`, it's meant to be used outside of it.

Given the way that you've written it, I think you should just use a local variable like this:

```
describe Exercise do
  describe 'Exercise properly normalizes values' do
    it 'has weight and weight unit if kind is Weight Lifting' do
      exercise = FactoryGirl.create(:lifting_exercise)
      exercise.should be_weight
      exercise.time.should be_nil
    end
    it 'has time but not weight etc. if kind is Cardio' do
      exercise = FactoryGirl.create(:aerobic_exercise)
      exercise.should be_time
      exercise.reps.should be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Also, given that you've included `FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods` in your `spec_helper` you don't need to prefix everything with `FactoryGirl`, you can just call it like this:

`exercise = create(:lifting_exercise)`

I hope that helps!

-Chad

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I used something basically identical to this to begin with, only I think I used 'Factory.create' instead of 'FactoryGirl.create' (I think I picked that up from some outdated tutorial??) and only changed it to the 'let' syntax after something that I Googled up seemed to suggest it.  I supposed I misunderstood though, your solution solved the issue.  Thanks again!

Comment: `let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:lifting_exercise) }` will work if you put it before all the it methods

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not RSpec and FactoryGirl not playing well together.

`let` is not part of an example's method group. Notice you have the `let` inside the `it` block. This should work

```
#require 'test/spec'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Exercise do

  describe 'Exercise properly normalizes values' do

    context 'with a lifting exercise' do
      let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:lifting_exercise) }

      it 'has weight and weight unit if kind is Weight Lifting' do
        exercise.should be_weight
        exercise.time.should be_nil
      end

    end

    context 'with an aerobic exercise' do
      let(:exercise) { FactoryGirl.create(:aerobic_exercise) }

      it 'has time but not weight etc. if kind is Cardio' do
        exercise.should be_time
        exercise.reps.should be_nil
      end

    end        

  end

end
```

**NOTE** `context` is just an alias for `describe`.